# How to separate a list of characters into 2 separate lists but maintain their order in python

Tags: python, list

This is what I have,

```
coordinates = ('S', 'W', 'W', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'N', 'N')
```

I would like to separate the list into 2 further lists (one containing the N and S values, the other containing the E and W values).
However, the need to remain in the order they appear i.e.

```
new_coordinates_one = ('S', 'S', 'S', 'N', 'N')
new_coordinates_two = ('W', 'W', 'E', 'E')
```

Comment: You say lists but you show tuples. Please make up your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension, as suggested by others, is a very Pythonic approach and is commendable.

However, one could argue that the iterable (*coordinates*) has to be parsed twice if that technique is used. Therefore, although the code isn't quite as neat, it can be done in one pass:

```
coordinates = ('S', 'W', 'W', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'N', 'N')

sn = []
ew = []

for c in coordinates:
    if c in 'SN':
        sn.append(c)
    else:
        ew.append(c) # assumption that if c is neither S nor N then it's either E or W


print(sn)
print(ew)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
new_coordinates_one = [s for s in coordinates if s in {'N', 'S'}]
new_coordinates_two = [s for s in coordinates if s in {'E', 'W'}]
```

Comment: nit: for small groups (under ~30 elements), membership check in a tuple/list is a smidge faster than a set. So, `... in ('N', 'S')` instead of `{'N', 'S'}`

Comment: Perfect, I spent so long trying to work that out. Very much appreciated

Comment: @Marat That disagrees with my memory, but I'm not sure I've tested it with strings. Can you share your benchmark?

Comment: @Marat Tuple is much **slower** in [my test](https://tio.run/##jVC9bgIxDN7zFN4uqU4ViAVVYmRlYeiAqugKThuJOJHPNyDUZz/O5IroVg9W/P05SbnId6bVuvA4Bs4JJCaMAjGVzAKMBTsx5pgznyJ1gj1swDb7poXm/dHu4/bvaVebgxdYLrSMOWEA36NY92ZgqkMPITP0EAmeN8RQsWsN2Tc/H7NZhnLG/9rtr91NdlV6RbmjL7SrOUPhMNBRGb1aO@@orJZMD06RbP0Kq@IWaEifyJulcw9d4UhipwBVvHpPXULvK185N443) even for this, i.e., already for **two** values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KellyBundy to my surprise, set is actually faster in **this case** - and I have no explanation for this. Still, I've observed on multiple occasions how tuples/lists are faster in similar context so I'd maintain they're usually faster on small groups

Comment: @Marat Can you show any example of that?

Comment: FWIW, using the short strings with the list comprehension is faster than either of set, list or tuple. The simplistic single pass approach (see my answer) is faster than any list comprehension (Python 3.10.5 on 3GHz Xeon in case that matters)

Comment: @KellyBundy I can't reproduce it anymore. I guess the difference is in Python version, I'll check and post the result later today

Comment: @KellyBundy yep, about 2x difference in favor of tuples in Python2 [link](https://tio.run/##jVC9jsIwDN7zFN6aoAodsCExsrIw3HBCUQEHIhEnSt3hhHj2UpOCYMODFX9/TpL@@Rxp3vcuxwDsA3oGH1LMDBkTNqzUIcZ89NQwtrACXW2rGqrfV3uM68/TpjQDE5j9SCl1RAe2RdZmqWCovxZczNCCJ3jf4F3BriVkW912o5m7dMFv7fppN4NdlFbQ3NAJ9WLMENh1dBBGrlaPOworxcODgyddvkKLuAbqwh7zambMS5eyJ9ZDgCim1lIT0NrCF870/R0)

Comment: @Marat [What do you mean by Python2 ? I've never heard of it ](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1511596558323748866). Easy explanation, that [builds the set every time](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSG@OLVEQ9OKSwEIoosV0vKLFIoVMvMUkvPzi1Iy8xJLUoHcNIhYtbqfuo6CerB6bSwXF1hzSWlBTiqx2jVg2jWB2jNzC/KLShRSMou5gFgPiDVATtHkKijKzCvRUNdVV9BSMDfXRMiC7dL8/x8A) while [Python 3 doesn't](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSG@OLVEQ9OKSwEIoosV0vKLFIoVMvMUkvPzi1Iy8xJLUoHcNIhYtbqfuo6CerB6bSwXF1hzSWlBTiqx2jVg2jWB2jNzC/KLShRSMou5gFgPiDVATtHkKijKzCvRUNdVV9BSMDfXRMiC7dL8/x8A).

Comment: @AlbertWinestein What do you mean with "using the short strings with the list comprehension"? And when you said yours is faster than the list comps, what input data did you use? (In my answer's benchmarks I see different relative speeds for small and larger data, as expected).

Comment: @KellyBundy My reference to 'short strings' is equivalent to your Kelly_listcomps_strings function. The data I used was as posted in the OP's question

Comment: @KellyBundy My reference to 'short strings' is equivalent to your Kelly_listcomps_strings function. The data I used was as posted in the OP's question.The timings are very different when the data set is larger

Answer (score 1):

```py
new_coordinates_one = tuple(coor for coor in coordinates if coor == 'S' or coor == 'N')
new_coordinates_two = tuple(coor for coor in coordinates if coor == 'W' or coor == 'E')
```

Alternatively, to reduce the size of the code incase if the conditions to check are too many, we can use the `in` operator to check if it matches any of the elements in the set. Credits: @Marat

```py
new_coordinates_one = tuple(coor for coor in coordinates if coor in ('N', 'S'))
new_coordinates_two = tuple(coor for coor in coordinates if coor in ('E', 'W'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Benchmarks (on 1000 times longer input) including three solutions from me (solutions modified as needed so they all return lists):

```
438 us +/- 2.2 us  Kelly_listcomp_append
537 us +/- 1.3 us  Kelly_oneloop_dict_append
562 us +/- 2.8 us  Timur_listcomps_sets
607 us +/- 2.0 us  Kelly_listcomps_strings
732 us +/- 3.5 us  Albert_oneloop_appends
918 us +/- 2.7 us  Marat_listcomps_tuples
966 us +/- 3.7 us  Quentin_listcomps_or
```

Benchmark with the original small input ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVVLb5tAEL7zK/YGNCSx21RqLXHowaeqlipX8sFCiMKQoMKCdodaVpTf7u7s8kw2tdXUB7zMNzsz37xojvhQ8w@fGnE6ZZCzr1CWx7jmUNZ1E2dFinHSNMAzL61rkRU8QZD@ymHqx2XA4MBCto9ujFIwHrWGOSoNMuRtQrqx1c91CIeA7dTT15p5LVjKCs4mboyX0c4@jbzUqAvAVnAVwU0cSyjzOKZQhhfHGbmUhcS0rprXecw5TO3vU2tgrMiN7NHduAFzt@4TU2pwUOFFZwORsURR8HtpTSmFcsaru9m60STyc@rrXac@ZI1iNKH9KKpWTEMDtMYFh3gipQYhz1J7lhbPcp6eyGoFD/VFVtZkZddb6Vm8DCmweTA8vyUiwQlPbJsS/h9Tr2fqv4Wp1zP138D0S/kTBA4jbJraxlRy3fbTEbhgFIeu2m7cUWrs3fQj5g8AlBLmamo65modS8nHrvzeAseCT@pVi8trRSLDgg6WqSBxGFK5WK9Frxv3r8W72Oxubnbt/mM185aneh/o669u5mACP1t2NmhYPwa0LQCD2EfGYPYmM5iteIETKT6irhgWFRTIiqqpBTJV7KQtMSapYInUsFEUCc/UX6coH9o8LztIYoLKeKGy08EVJKp9JGbw23GmdQnVUG3NUPUP/bqenzbm4TtUX8o71Vfn33RaozKGHglmbRhoHbXteVJBHPuOQ/GT10cCVmqk2AuLT7rFiYPUFrtmRl1qZO/YEj7rW0hXpKIHmaft7kk98ver5SKa9VTuPlJ8lAUPpe@v7p7oU3J1e800oBNjkPcacTXRmByoPN@D93HRbwWTaB2ZHL/NlpwY/w0kqAJfLtRvEJNkfHvmytzx51sBF@oKkfT8mVyAVP2hsBe5n19f2q8juwoJvFYOZkAGZWd7DHpMcb@hkN12FOed0RVFJyNgv@AY6nL602aZFPh5m5xOfwA)):

```
 980 ns +/-  4 ns  Kelly_listcomp_append
 997 ns +/-  5 ns  Albert_oneloop_appends
1203 ns +/-  2 ns  Timur_listcomps_sets
1225 ns +/-  6 ns  Kelly_listcomps_strings
1236 ns +/-  4 ns  Kelly_oneloop_dict_append
1615 ns +/-  5 ns  Marat_listcomps_tuples
1628 ns +/-  6 ns  Quentin_listcomps_or
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVVLa9tAEL7rV8xNUqI4NqWlGHTowadSQ3HBByOEKo0SUWkldlc1weS3uzu7ejqbxjTNQdmd@XZmvnm5eZKPNfvwueHnc4Y5fMWyfIprhmVdN3FWpDJOmgZZ5qV1zbOCJRKFv3ZA/TERAB4hhEO0MKBgPGqEOSoEGfK2Ib3Y6e8mxGMAe/X1NTKvOaRQMJi4MV5GO4c08lID5yhbzlQEizgWWOZxTKEMF8cZuZSFkGldNa/zmHOY2j@k1sCgyI3s5G7dANyd@wwKhkcVXvRmICIWkhfsQVhTSqG84dXd7txoEvlb8M2@gw9ZoxhNaD@KquXT0FBa48JjPJFSg5BnoT0Li2cxT09ktSKP9VVWNmRl31vpWbwMKbB5MDy/JTyRE56ybUr8f0y9nqn/HqZez9R/B9Mv5U/kchhh09Q2poLptp@OwBWjOHTVbuuOUmNv0Y@YPyiwFDiHqemYwzqWgo1d@b1FJgs2qVfNr68ViQwLOlimgsRhSOWCHkXXrfvX4l1tdj83u3H/sZp5y1K9D/TzVzdzMFFfLDubalg/RmlbAEZjHxmjszeZ0dmKFziR4sPrCmRRYSGhqJqaS1DFTtpSxiTlkAitNkCesEz964Disc3zslMJmUhlvFDZ6dQVJqp9hMzwt@NM6xKqodqZoeo/@rqZn7bm4ztUX8o71Vfn33RaozImPRLM2jDQGLXtWVJhHPtz3zchrJbLpUOcKJITgddqzOCFl2fd9sRLaC9dg0tdfgk3sMJP@pWkJ0JRxszTdg8Ej/zDerWMZn2WuyeKmTLjSeH7z9AKuL2/g5NOE8nWi1Wuxa7mHZNtlfYH9D4u@yVh8q6DEuNPtSVFxnWDiQTiPcjoOt4u/JgH/nxDyKV6QuQ8fybnKFSvKN2LOsyfr@zPJdyGpLxTDmaKDMvO9hj0mNp@W0m47/jNu6Qrhs5EAL/wKdRl9KeNMynsZcucz38A)):

```
def Kelly_oneloop_dict_append(coordinates):
    ns, ew = [].append, [].append
    append = dict(N=ns, S=ns, E=ew, W=ew)
    for c in coordinates:
        append[c](c)
    return ns.__self__, ew.__self__

def Kelly_listcomp_append(coordinates):
    ew = [].append
    return [c for c in coordinates if c in {'N', 'S'} or ew(c)], ew.__self__

def Kelly_listcomps_strings(coordinates):
    ns = [c for c in coordinates if c in 'NS']
    ew = [c for c in coordinates if c in 'EW']
    return ns, ew

def Timur_listcomps_sets(coordinates):
    new_coordinates_one = [s for s in coordinates if s in {'N', 'S'}]
    new_coordinates_two = [s for s in coordinates if s in {'E', 'W'}]
    return new_coordinates_one, new_coordinates_two

def Marat_listcomps_tuples(coordinates):
    new_coordinates_one = [s for s in coordinates if s in ('N', 'S')]
    new_coordinates_two = [s for s in coordinates if s in ('E', 'W')]
    return new_coordinates_one, new_coordinates_two

def Albert_oneloop_appends(coordinates):
    sn = []
    ew = []
    for c in coordinates:
        if c in 'SN':
            sn.append(c)
        else:
            ew.append(c)
    return sn, ew

def Quentin_listcomps_or(coordinates):
    new_coordinates_one = [coor for coor in coordinates if coor == 'S' or coor == 'N']
    new_coordinates_two = [coor for coor in coordinates if coor == 'W' or coor == 'E']
    return new_coordinates_one, new_coordinates_two

funcs = [
    Kelly_oneloop_dict_append,
    Kelly_listcomp_append,
    Kelly_listcomps_strings,
    Timur_listcomps_sets,
    Marat_listcomps_tuples,
    Albert_oneloop_appends,
    Quentin_listcomps_or,
]

from timeit import default_timer as time
from random import shuffle
from statistics import mean, stdev

coordinates = ('S', 'W', 'W', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'N', 'N')
for func in funcs:
    print(func(coordinates), func.__name__)

coordinates *= 1000
times = {func: [] for func in funcs}
def stats(func):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[func])[:10]]
    return f'{int(mean(ts))} us +/- {stdev(ts):.1f} us '
for _ in range(50):
    shuffle(funcs)
    for func in funcs:
        repeat = 10
        t = 0
        for _ in range(repeat):
            t0 = time()
            result = func(coordinates)
            t1 = time()
            t += t1 - t0
            del result
        times[func].append(t / repeat)
for func in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(func), func.__name__)
```